# Что быстрей и правильней работает при выборке MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такой запрос с таблицы order

```
SELECT * FROM order WHERE subcat IN ('musub1', 'musub2', 'musub3')
```

Я думаю лучше сделать промежуточную таблицу в которой будут хранится ид подкатегорий и ид order получается такой запрос

```
SELECT subcat.* FROM subcat  LEFT JOIN subcat_order s ON (s.id_sub = subcat.id AND s.order_id = $id);
```

Запрос сложнее и надежней но быстрей ли он будет и оптимальней чем первый запрос.  Или можно както повозится с первым запросом что-бы его оптимизировать. Проблема в том если у меня в имени подкатегории попадается апостроф например

SELECT * FROM order WHERE subcat IN ('mus'ub1', 'musub2', 'musub3') то MySql дает канечно ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

экранировать одинарную кавычку внутри строки, заключённой в одинарные же кавычки, можно путём её удвоения:

```
'mus''ub1'
```

вопрос же скорости выполнения запросов, вероятно, довольно обширен, и в наибольшей степени зависит, насколько я это себе представляю, от наличия/отсутствия индексов по участвующим в запросе полям, и от объёма хранимых данных.

но у индексов есть и «обратная сторона»: большее время уходит на добавление строк (а, скорее всего, и модификацию).